# Messaging APIs for iPhone and Android

Tags: iphone, android, ios, notifications, messaging

What are good APIs/services for offering in-app notifications for Android and iOS devices?

We need to send notifications in real-time.  The notifications need to get sent independent of whether the user has the app open at the time.

Should we build from scratch or outsource?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you solve your problem or are you looking for an "in app" notification system?

Comment: Didn't solve the problem yet.  Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS offers PUSH notifications, which you send through Apple's servers.
They have a quick reference here: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3576

If you want your service to run on older versions of android (pre-2.2) you probably need to develop something from scratch (I would derive something from XMPP), but Android 2.2+ offers something called C2DM ([Cloud to Device Messaging](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/index.html)) which is quite useful.